# copy unknown sized array to another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of numbers 1 - 1000000 (one million + in no perticular order)
I would like to copy the array to another array

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("DeadPeopleTZ.rpt");
 textBox1.AppendText(myInt.ToString() + "\n");
             string[] target;
             Array.Copy(lines, target);
```

Comment: and the question/problem is? Array.Copy will do just what you asked

Comment: Just wondering that there are no answers marked as accepted. Let me know if they do not suit you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you *could* create the array to the right size and then use `Array.Copy`:

```
string[] target = new string[lines.Length];
Array.Copy(lines, target, lines.Length);
```

But it would be easier to clone it:

```
string[] target = (string[]) lines.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

The size you want for your `target` array is the same size that `lines` has - so the size is not unknown at *run time*:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("DeadPeopleTZ.rpt");
string[] target = new string[lines.Length];
Array.Copy(lines, target, lines.Length);
```